# How do I pass Text Field values in a Java Script function?

Tags: javascript

I am new to java script, I have three text fields with ids text1, text2, text3 respectively. I want to input values in 2 of them and print the sum in the third.

my code looks like this please tell me, what am I doing wrong.
it is adding them as string not numbers.

Also I want to make it like, if I enter value in any 2 of the three boxes. The other one adjusts itself.
EX: '__' + 5 = 7  =>  ' 2 ' + 5 = 7
will it work if I put variables in value attribute. if So then How?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function myCalculator(a, b) {
      c = a + b;
      document.getElementById("text3").value = c;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <input type="text" value="" id="text1"></input> + <input type="text" value="" id="text2"></input> = <input type="text" value="" id="text3"></input>
    <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick='myCalculator(document.getElementById("text1").value,document.getElementById("text2").value)'></input>
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You may want to look at [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `parseInt(text)` on both parameters of `myCalculator` function to convert them to numbers first.

```
function myCalculator(a,b){
    a = parseInt(a, 10); // convert to integer first
    b = parseInt(b, 10);

    c=a+b;
    document.getElementById("text3").value = c;
}
```

The second parameter of `parseInt` function is radix, which needs to be 10 to read numbers in decimal system. It is 10 by default from ES5.

Comment: It is always wise to specify the `radix` when using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. 
but what is the conceptual difference between parsInt() and Number()

Comment: `Number` is object wrapper, see (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), `parseInt` is native function for reading numbers from strings.

Comment: `parseInt('3a', 10)` will give you `3` whereas `Number('3a')` will give you `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Number() to convert the strings to numbers. Anything inside a text input.value will initially be a string.

```
function myCalculator(a, b) {
    var c = Number(a) + Number(b);
    document.getElementById("text3").value = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your Code this with text block , First remember to pass id in quotes and second format your value from string to javascript before adding.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function myCalculator(a,b){
    var c=parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
    document.getElementById('text3').value = c;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <input type="text" value="" id="text1"></input> + <input type="text" value="" id="text2"></input> = <input type="text" value="" id="text3"></input>
    <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick='myCalculator(document.getElementById("text1").value,document.getElementById("text2").value)'></input>
    </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```